# Intranet URL with Facebook authentication

Tags: c#, facebook, forms-authentication

I'm trying to log into my application with FB. The matter is, when I put an url like

```
http://mywebsite
```

Which is a valid intranet url, I get the message "URL must be in a valid domain".

Is there any workaround for this ? (The application already works with the URL : `http://localhost:29666/`)

Thx

Comment: It might be valid within your intranet, but it is not a valid domain (which means at minimum it must be resolvable through public DNS).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Actually it worked with the localhost value, and I've just tried it with `http://tadaa.foo`, I'm not sure these are resolvable through public DNS

Comment: In that case it probably only expects at least a two-part hostname.

Comment: Well seems it did the trick :) Thx !